# Using variable to pull data from a DataFrame in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I am trying to get columns A,B,and C lined up next to each other in a new dataframe.

I have 15 columns for each letter. I tried to create a for-loop to loop through them so that A1,B1,C1 are next to each other up until A15,B15,and C15 are next to each other as well.

```
def organize_data(df):

rng = int(input('How many peptides do you have to analyze:  '))

number = 1
frames = []
for i in range(rng):
    if number == 16:
        break
    else:
        Ax='A'+ str(number)
        Bx='B'+ str(number)
        Cx='C'+ str(number)

        A = df.Ax[:41]
        B = df.Bx[:41]
        C = df.Cx[:41]
        dfABC = pd.concat([A,B,C], axis=1)
        frames.append(dfABC)
        number = number+1 

df1 = pd.concat(frames)
return(df1)
```

I keep getting this error:
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Ax'

Is there a way to get around this?

Here is my data set that I'm trying to organize:[image] The "Wavelength" cell is at B29.

Comment: It seems you need `A = df.iloc[:41, df.columns.get_loc(Ax)]`

Comment: If you're trying to dynamically access columns, you'll need to use the `[...]` notation.

Comment: I reopen question because better solution is in my comment - `df[Ax][:41]` is not nice solution and multiple `][` creates chaining indexing.

Comment: Can you show example of your data and fix the indentation please?

Comment: @zipa i just edited the question to include a picture of my data

Answer (score 2):

You need [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with [`get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) if need select first 41 rows with custom column name:

```
A = df.iloc[:41, df.columns.get_loc(Ax)]
```

EDIT:

I change solution completely - idea is use `MultiIndex` in columns with level with `strings` and numbers. Then sort it by second numeric level and last filter by `rng`. `concat` function is not necessary.

Sample:

```
np.random.seed(100)
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([list('ABC'), range(1,16)])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(3,45)), columns=mux)
df.columns = [''.join((x[0], str(x[1]))) for x in df.columns]
print (df)
   A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6  A7  A8  A9  A10 ...   C6  C7  C8  C9  C10  C11  \
0   8   8   3   7   7   0   4   2   5    2 ...    9   3   2   5    8    1   
1   0   8   2   5   1   8   1   5   4    2 ...    6   6   0   7    2    3   
2   3   7   9   0   0   5   9   6   6    5 ...    9   0   9   8    6    2   

   C12  C13  C14  C15  
0    0    7    6    2  
1    5    4    2    4  
2    0    5    3    2  

[3 rows x 45 columns]
```

---

```
#helper df 
df1 = df.columns.to_series().str.extract('([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)', expand=True)
#convert second column to int
df1[1] = df1[1].astype(int)
#create MultiIndex from df1
df.columns = df1.T.values.tolist()
#sort second level
df = df.sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
print (df)
   A  B  C  A  B  C  A  B  C  A ...  C  A  B  C  A  B  C  A  B  C
  1  1  1  2  2  2  3  3  3  4  ... 12 13 13 13 14 14 14 15 15 15
0  8  4  7  8  0  7  3  9  0  7 ...  0  1  7  7  0  1  6  8  1  2
1  0  3  2  8  6  4  2  3  2  5 ...  5  5  7  4  0  6  2  9  6  4
2  3  2  8  7  3  5  9  8  2  0 ...  0  7  4  5  3  8  3  9  9  2

#filter by condition
rng = 4
df2 = df.loc[:, df.columns.get_level_values(1) <= rng]
#convert MultiIndex to columns
df2.columns = [''.join((x[0], str(x[1]))) for x in df2.columns]
print (df2)
   A1  B1  C1  A2  B2  C2  A3  B3  C3  A4  B4  C4
0   8   4   7   8   0   7   3   9   0   7   6   2
1   0   3   2   8   6   4   2   3   2   5   4   7
2   3   2   8   7   3   5   9   8   2   0   7   7
```

All together in function:

```
def organize_data(df):

    rng = int(input('How many peptides do you have to analyze:  '))

    df1 = df.columns.to_series().str.extract('([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)', expand=True)
    df1[1] = df1[1].astype(int)
    df.columns = df1.T.values.tolist()
    df = df.sort_index(level=1, axis=1)

    df2 = df.loc[:, df.columns.get_level_values(1) <= rng]
    df2.columns = [''.join((x[0], str(x[1]))) for x in df2.columns]
    return df2

a = organize_data(df)
print (a)
```

Comment: This did the trick for me! My only issue now is aligning the data correctly in the final dataframe